# Storing Salt as Plaintext in a File Containing Cryptotext

Tags: c#, regex, security, encryption, salt

My question is this:

Doesn't storing the salt as plaintext defeat the purpose of having a
salt (which I've heard is fine to do)? I was of the impression that the salt is meant to be an additional variable providing added
complexity for a brute-force or dictionary attack, by causing any attempt to convert the correct password to the key to fail unless thecorrect salt is supplied. It seems to me that if the salt is known, the attacker can try each password with the correct salt. If not, why?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Salted Hashed Password with Python (Different salt for every new password)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065325/salted-hashed-password-with-python-different-salt-for-every-new-password)

Comment: It's similar, but that seems to cover where to store the salt, not either of the questions I asked specifically. I know how to handle password hashing and the storage of a salt in the users table of a database, that's not what I'm asking. The accepted answer does answer one of my questions, but doesn't explain why. I already know that it's fine in theory, I want to know the reasoning. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of a salt is to prevent an attacker from reusing his dictionary for multiple ciphertexts.
There is nothing wrong with revealing the salt.

Instead, you should make sure that your salt is never re-used by a different ciphertext.
To do that, you should create salts using a secure random number generator.

Comment: @lukas: Ask about the hash algorithm, not whether to salt or not.  In short, yes.  And, use PBKDFv2 or bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: @Rook are you now advocating *not* using salt?! If so, what happened to Rook?

Comment: @Jacco **no**,  I'm saying if you don't know the value of the salt then you need to make a lot more guesses.  The question is:  should the op store the salt in a file.  And SLaks isn't considering the security impact of storing the salt in a file. -1 for slaks,  for lack of imagination.

Comment: @Rook, Ok, that clears it up nicely : ) Can I ask you to add your view to [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough)

Comment: @Rook, I'd like to hear your opinion on storing the salt in a file if you have one.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't storing the salt as plaintext defeat the purpose of having a salt (which I've heard is fine to do)?

**Why do you use salt?**
To store passwords securely you hash them. And you store a list of those Hashes. When you know the Hash it is incredibly hard to find the original password.

Suppose you are an attacker who has retreived a list of hashed passwords. You could take some geusses. You could try to hash some week passwords as: "password", "qwerty", ... And then search through the list of hashed passwords for a match. The chance you can guess a single password correctly is quite high.

Salt is a technique to prevent you from doing this. When you want to take a guess. e.g: take "qwerty". You should hash "qwerty" + salt. This will be different for every user. What makes it a lot harder to guess passwords.

Briefly: storing salt as plain text is perfectly secure.

Comment: Thanks, but does that also apply when you are dealing with an application designed to encrypt text documents? An attacker wouldn't be searching for the key to a bunch of passwords; they'd merely be trying to gain access to as little as one text file, so the salt could be incorporated into the cracking algorithm, am I right? Also, I'm not sure that it matters, but I'm using AES-256, not a hash algorithm.

Comment: Although the key is a hash of the salt and password.

Comment: To answer my own question in the comment above from a few years ago, yes and no. The salt's only purpose is to prevent attacks on multiple cyphertexts at the same time. If an attacker is brute-forcing one single file, (or password) the salt provides no additional security. By hiding the salt, you are attempting to use the salt to make up for a weak password, which is ineffective and not it's intended purpose.